# Path Traversal with rawurldecode and dots validation

Tags: php, server, directory-traversal

I'm trying to check if it's possible to bypass a two dots verification to perform a Path Traversal, downloading files out of the allowed folder. The problem is that it uses [rawurldecode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.rawurldecode.php) when validating the submitted file, so URL Encoding techniques didn't work.

This is how the application tries to prevent Path Traversal:

```
<?php
if ( stristr( rawurldecode( $file ), '..' ) ) {
    return;
}
if ( file_exists( 'allowed-dir/' . rawurldecode( $file ) ) {
    send_file();
}
```

I got the idea from [this article](https://octagon.net/blog/2022/01/22/cve-2021-45467-cwp-centos-web-panel-preauth-rce/) and created a fuzzer to check every character and test against the file_exists function:

```
<?php
function unichr( $c ) {
    if ( $c <= 0x7F ) {
        return chr( $c );
    } elseif ( $c <= 0x7FF ) {
        return chr( 0xC0 | $c >> 6 ) . chr( 0x80 | $c & 0x3F );
    } elseif ( $c <= 0xFFFF ) {
        return chr( 0xE0 | $c >> 12 ) . chr( 0x80 | $c >> 6 & 0x3F ) . chr( 0x80 | $c & 0x3F );
    } elseif ( $c <= 0xFFFF ) {
        return chr( 0xE0 | $c >> 18 ) . chr( 0x80 | $c >> 12 & 0x3F ) . chr( 0x80 | $c >> 6 & 0x3F ) . chr( 0x80 | $c & 0x3F );
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

for ( $unicode = 0; $unicode < 0xffff; $unicode++ ) {
    if ( file_exists( 'example-dir/.' . rawurldecode( unichr( $unicode ) ) . './fuzz.php' ) ) {
        echo 'success';
    }
}
```

None of them worked. Any ideas if this could be bypassed?

Comment: The `file_exists` is not your problem (you probably want to `send_file` existing ones). You want to escape from `allowed-dir/` (I assume you would actually call `send_file('allowed-dir/' . rawurldecode( $file ));`)

Comment: The `send_file` was just an example. I need a way to have a string that bypasses the ".." stri verification, but also works to leave the "allowed-dir" directory.